# CentOS 5.9 | Program Listening on Port, Causing It Not To Bind

Tags: centos

I have a game server running on my CentOS box that binds to port 28960, now when I restarted the game server it stated that it can't bind the port because its in use, but its obviously because the server was restarted, but the port was not closed? How do I check to see if the program is listening, and if its not, then how would I clear the port, so I can start the server back up on port 28960?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be running into the [2*MSL problem](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/listen_on_a_tcp_port_with_connections_in_the_time_wait_state.html). Here's how you tell:

```
$ netstat -na | grep 28960.*TIME_WAIT
```

If you get anything back from that, it means the kernel's network stack is waiting for twice the maximum segment lifetime (MSL) for stray packets to get around to making an appearance before allowing that port to be re-bound. [The `TIME_WAIT` state is a good thing.](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.7.shtml)

Servers that are intended to be restarted in normal operation disable `TIME_WAIT` handling by setting the [`SO_REUSEADDR` socket option](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml). If you look into the docs for your game server, it may be that there is an option that lets you enable this behavior.

If not, and you can't get the source to modify the game server, your only option is to wait for the `TIME_WAIT` states to expire, which typically takes between 30 and 120 seconds.

Here is a script I call `showwait` which is helpful with this sort of thing:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
while [ true ]
do
    netstat -na | grep WAIT
    sleep 1
done
```

You just run it and wait for it to stop putting out lines every second. Then you <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> it and move on with whatever you needed to do that required that there be no wait states.

This script isn't suitable for use on a busy server, where there are wait states going on all the time, but when you're just waiting for a server with nothing else going on to achieve quiescence, it's perfect.

Comment: Right. But this should not take too much time to clear up.

Comment: @vonbrand: As I said, typically 30-120 seconds. I don't see anything from our anonymous OP that tells us he actually waited that long. In one of the comments on your post he said it "never" clears up, but that's obviously bogus.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `lsof(8)` (check the manual page, it is quite extensive; but just piping its output to `grep 28960` should give some idea what is going on). In any case, port 28960 is unassigned by [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml). so nothing should be using it.

Comment: Yeah, 28960 is the default port used for Call of Duty 4, the game server I was trying to start up, but when I first started it, it binded to 28960, then on restart, it never stopped being binded, causing the software to think its already binded.

Comment: cod4_lnxd  6610    root   24u  IPv4 827763      0t0  UDP *:28960

Found it =] Now how would I find out how to close it if its not showing up on my tasks?

Comment: @user31186, when the process exits it releases the ports it is using. So there can't be any "leftover bindings". Very strange.

Comment: @user31186, `kill 6610` would get rid of that process which holds that port. `kill -s KILL 6610` if it doesn't want to go.

Comment: @user31186, that line matches but isn't for the port you are checking. If that is the only match, the port is free. Does `nmap(8)` see something there?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Yep, that was it. But the weirdest thing was that it wasn't showing when I looked at any process lists...But I learned something new today =] thanks all.